# WkHtmlToPDF UTF 8

Tags: asp.net, .net, wkhtmltopdf, meta

I am currently using WkHtmlToXDotNet which implements WkHtmlToPdf and characters with tilde like `ó` are appearing as `?`. I even added on my html header the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

It didn't work: am I missing anything?

Comment: Make sure you have set UTF-8 everywhere. This could be a string issue, an OS issue or one of many others. Can you show us the command that is passed to wkhtmltopdf? Or the code that you use to call wkhtmltoxdotnet? By the way: not sure if meta, asp.net and .net are related to the issue, but I left the tags there anyway, someone might come and remove them because there doesn't seem to be much in relation to them as the question is now.

Comment: Only when it goes through the wkhtmltopdf it has this problem when I see the html on the browser the correct characters are shown I am not passing a command I am using var pdfData = HtmlToXConverter.ConvertToPdf(fullHtml); the WkHtmlToXDotNet Wrapper on the cpp proyect there is this line auto pointerToValue = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(value);which I believe could be the cause

Comment: Characters are showing correctly after editing the c++ line and changing it with this array<Byte>^ pointerToValue = Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(value);

 pin_ptr<Byte> pinnedBytes = &pointerToValue[0];